# Using "could" for future events

Tags: modal-verbs

We use *could* to show that something is possible in the future, but not certain:

> If we don’t hurry we could be late. (i.e., perhaps/maybe we will be late)

Why is it incorrect to say this:

> I couldn't be present tomorrow'? (i.e., Perhaps I won't be here tomorrow).

Comment: The question is unanswerable unless you edit the post to clarify what you want. The way I see it, this is what they call an XY problem over on StackOverflow: You're fixated on a particular modal auxilliary (can) when the problem hinges on the subjunctive mood (can -> could).

Comment: So, 'I couldn't be present tomorrow' is incorrect, then what about ' I can't be present tomorrow.?

Comment: It's an ambiguity too far.

Comment: Actually, 'I couldn't possibly attend tomorrow' is idiomatic.

Comment: Mixing modals and negatives leads to a situation where dictionary meanings are useless; everything's idiomatic.

Comment: On it's own _I couldn't be present tomorrow_ is unacceptable -- _can't_ is required. But you could say _I'm sure I said that I couldn't be present tomorrow_.

Comment: Without the contraction and with a bit of emphasis this could work as suggested. "I _could_ not be present tomorrow" would be the opposite of "I _could_ be present tomorrow". It would mean that the speaker was suggesting that he deliberately absent himself, perhaps to give some advantage to the other person by his absence. However using the contraction makes the selective emphasis impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's correct to say *I couldn't be present tomorrow*, but only if the pragmatic context makes sense for the listener. It will not fly as an example sentence in an English class because these tend to have "out of the blue" background information, and some modal expressions require background information to be felicitous.

When the modal verb is in its preterite form, it expresses remoteness rather than past time. The only different in meaning between *I can't be present tomorrow* and *I couldn't be present tomorrow* is that in the first case, the speaker's presence is not negotiable. In the second case, it could be that they are open to incentives, or that they are trying to dissuade the listener from formally asking them to be present.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using *"might not"*:

*"I might not be present tomorrow."*

"could not" is almost always found in sentences in the past tense with a completely different meaning to the verb:

*"I could not complete the task."*
as a substitute for:
*"I was not able to complete the task."*

Answer (score 0):

In normal circumstances, people will say "I won't be able to be present tomorrow."

"I couldn't be present tomorrow" can only be interpreted as "I wouldn't be able to be present tomorrow(due to an implied condition).